# Trying to access keys and values from a nested dictionary is not working whatsoever

Tags: python, dictionary

I've been trying to access the keys and values of an inner dictionary for the past couple hours and I can't seem to be able to do it.

I've tried everything I know, everything I could find online, to the point where I can't even post anything I've tried but even then it would be a waste of time since it's not working.

Here's my list of dictionaries:

```
tagsList = [
{
    "name": "Type",
    "tagValues": {
        "type_tag_div1_class_name": f"{tag_values.type_tag_div1_class_name}",

        "type_tag_div2_class_name": f"{tag_values.type_tag_div2_class_name}",
        "type_tag_div2_jsan_name": f"{tag_values.type_tag_div2_jsan_name}",

        "type_tag_div3_class_name": f"{tag_values.type_tag_div3_class_name}",
        "type_tag_div3_jsan_name": f"{tag_values.type_tag_div3_jsan_name}",

        "type_tag_div4_class_name": f"{tag_values.type_tag_div4_class_name}",
        "type_tag_div4_jsan_name": f"{tag_values.type_tag_div4_jsan_name}"
    }
},
{
    "name": "Name",
    "tagValues": {
        "name_tag_div1_class_name": f"{tag_values.name_tag_div1_class_name}",
        "name_tag_div1_jsan_name": f"{tag_values.name_tag_div1_jsan_name}",

        "name_tag_h1_class_name": f"{tag_values.name_tag_h1_class_name}",
        "name_tag_h1_jsan_name": f"{tag_values.name_tag_h1_jsan_name}",

        "name_tag_span_class_name": f"{tag_values.name_tag_span_class_name}"
    }
},
{
    "name": "Address",
    "tagValues": {
        "address_tag_button_class_name": f"{tag_values.address_tag_button_class_name}",

        "address_tag_div1_class_name": f"{tag_values.address_tag_div1_class_name}",

        "address_tag_div2_class_name": f"{tag_values.address_tag_div2_class_name}",
        "address_tag_div2_jsan_name": f"{tag_values.address_tag_div2_jsan_name}",

        "address_tag_div3_class_name": f"{tag_values.address_tag_div3_class_name}",
        "address_tag_div3_jsan_name": f"{tag_values.address_tag_div3_jsan_name}"
    }
]
```

I'm trying to iterate over each dictionary's `tagValues` 's keys and values.
When I tried, in multiple ways, the closest I get to be able to manipulate the keys and values is by doing this:

```
for dictionary in tagsList:

    k = dictionary['tagValues'].keys()
    v = dictionary['tagValues'].values()

    for keys in k:
        print(keys)

    for values in v:
        print(values)
```

Otherwise, I get a string as such:

`dict_keys(['name_tag_div1_class_name', 'name_tag_div1_jsan_name', ...]): dict_values(['TIHn2', ...`

or

`{'mood_tag_div1_class_name': 'UmE4Qe', 'mood_tag_div2_class_name': 'C7xf8b', ... }`
but this is a string.

How can I access the keys and values of this inner dictionary in order to use them ?

Comment: It returns the dictionary as a string basically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already iterating over the correct values. The only thing you can shorten would be creating an inner loop:

```py
for dictionary in tagsList:
    for key, item in dictionary["tagValues"].items():
        print(key, item)
```

Comment: Bro I can't thank you enough, I must've not tried that combination of `['key'].items()`. You're awesome

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code example of nested dictionaries.
In your example your second nested dictionary contains NON-dictionary items.
You will not be able to iterate in a third nested loop.

```
nested_dictionary = \
{
    "dict1" : {
        "value1": 1,
        "value2": 2
    },
    "dict2" :{
        "value3": 1,
        "value4": 2
    }
}

for outer_key, outer_value in nested_dictionary.items():
    print(f"{outer_key} : {outer_value}")
    for inner_key, inner_value in outer_value.items():
        print(f"\t{inner_key} : {inner_value}")
```